# How to change styling of modal dialogue in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to change the position and background color of modal dialogue in google apps script for my addon
I have searched a lot but only found answers using UiApp which is now deprecated and no longer works. I found no answers for doing this using HtmlService.
Only available function in after createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index') are :
setWidth and
setHeight
which work perfectly but i need to change position of modal too.
Is there any way to do this at the moment?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the position of the modal window. The sidebar dialog is also static. However, you can use CSS properties to control the look of everything inside the dialogs.

Here is a link to the best practices for developing add-ons: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of, at least, changing the stile of the dialogue box iteself? I can change its inner context to use some fancy bootstrap style, but the dialogue itself is pretty much the good ol' cold rectangle, and that's it.

Comment: There are methods that allow you to setHeight and setWidth... but as far as I know that is it :(