# Make a floating control panel whose size can be changed by mouse in Google Sheets add-ons

Tags: google-apps-script, dialog, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I would like to make a Google Sheets add-on. Most of the existing Google Sheets add-ons open a sidebar on the right of Google Sheets. But the sidebar is very narrow (i.e., `300px`), we cannot change its width, it's not convenient at all.

So I'm thinking how to propose a bigger panel to host my add-on. I have seen and tried [this add-on](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/formula_studio/142258573752). It opens a dialog-like window above the content of the sheets, the size is changeable.

[image]

On the other hide, I tried the following code in Apps Script. It does open a dialog but the size cannot be changed by mouse.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('My Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show Dialog', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function showDialog() {
  // Create HTML output object
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Hello, World!</p>')
      .setWidth(400) // Set width
      .setHeight(300); // Set height
  
  // Display modal dialog with the title 'My Dialog'
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My Dialog');
}
```

Does anyone know how to make a floating panel like the example add-on whose size can be changed by mouse?

**Edit 1:** I realize that we can change the position for both model dialog and modeless dialog, we just need to drag the right position (where the title is).

Comment: Does this answer or gives you an idea?: [How to change styling of modal dialogue in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094714/how-to-change-styling-of-modal-dialogue-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: Unfortunately the custom dialog has a maximum height and width that won't let you fill the window.  It is limited to the size of the sheet minus a margin all around.  You can move a custom dialog but you can't set the position through app script.

Comment: I agree with @TheWizEd, Here's another one: [Responsive ModalDialog/ModelessDialog Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66683041/responsive-modaldialog-modelessdialog-google-script) .

Comment: @Twilight and TheWizEd I modified slightly the OP to make it clearer. The links you gave show there is no solution? But how does Formula Studio make it happen, in your opinion?

Comment: 1.Could you add a gif/screenrecord showing the requested feature in the question? I and probably others don't want to install the app due to the wide range of permissions requested by the app - not to mention the completely paid feature of the app. 2. Could you also describe the exact button combination used to resize the dialog and the browser used?

Answer (score 1):

*From @Mogsdad's answer:*

> *Everything that you can do to the Google Sheets UI via Google Apps Script is documented in [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).*

On the other hand, It is not possible to use the mouse to directly resize or reposition a `modal dialog` box that has been launched in Google Sheets when using Apps Script.

you can use the **`setWidth`, `setHeight` methods** in Apps Script to set the dialog box's initial size programmatically (as what you have used in your example code).

For more information about the `ModalDialog box`:[Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title)

Aside from the links I shared in the comment section, Here are additional references:

- [Can I reposition a modeless dialog in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187066/can-i-reposition-a-modeless-dialog-in-google-sheets)
- [Can I somehow dock the searchbox (ctrl +f) or create a new searchbox in the top menu in Google Sheets so that it is always visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987984/can-i-somehow-dock-the-searchbox-ctrl-f-or-create-a-new-searchbox-in-the-top)

Comment: Thank you. As you said, it seems that users cannot change the size of the dialog by  dragging and dropping the boarders.

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking for [`Modeless` dialog functionality](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodelessdialoguserinterface,-title). Try

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'My Dialog');
```

To quote the docs,

> Modeless dialogs let the user interact with the editor behind the dialog. By contrast, modal dialogs do not

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it, users cannot change the size of the dialog by dragging and dropping the boarders.